# Cannot get file in Download directory to delete using File.delete() on android studio

Tags: java, android

Here is my current code. I am very new to programming and Android Studio. I assumed that there is a stupid logic error somewhere in here but have checked it over (and over, and over) and cannot for the life of me figure out why files will not delete.

The intention is for the bottom bar to come up when an item/items are long clicked and the DEL button will appear and when the user confirms, the file will delete. However, the files will not delete/be removed from the list of items after confirming.

Please help! Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout1);


    }

    class TextAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        // String array of items in a directory
        private List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        // Boolean array to store which items are selected in list
        private boolean[] selection;

        public void setData(List<String> data){
            if(data != null){
                this.data.clear();
                if(data.size() > 0){
                    this.data.addAll(data);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        void setSelection(boolean[] selection){
            if(selection != null){
                // Creating new array copy
                this.selection = new boolean[selection.length];
                // Populating new array copy
                for (int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++){
                    this.selection[i] = selection[i];
                }
                // Notifying that data changed
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return data.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
                convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textItem)));
            }
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            final String path = getItem(position);
            holder.info.setText(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1));
            if(selection != null){
                if(selection[position]){
                    holder.info.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                }
                else{
                    holder.info.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder{
            TextView info;

            ViewHolder(TextView info){
                this.info = info;
            }
        }
    }

    // Checking permissions
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 1234;
    // String array storing read/write external storage permission
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            // Requires min SDK version 16
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    // Asking for 2 permissions
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_COUNT = 2;

    // Return boolean for if permissions will be granted
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private boolean arePermissionsDenied(){
        int p = 0;
        while (p < PERMISSIONS_COUNT){
        // If permission is not granted
            if(checkSelfPermission(PERMISSIONS[p]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                return true;
            }
            p++;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // Flag to check if file manager is intialized
    private boolean isFileManagerInit = false;
    // Stores which items are selected in manager for modifying/opening
    private boolean[] selection;

    private File[] files;

    private List<String>filesList;

    private int filesFoundCount;

    // OnResume
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        // If build is Marshmellow or higher, we have to ask for permissions
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && arePermissionsDenied()) {
            // Requesting for permissions
            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
        }
        // Checking if File Manager has been initialized. If not, initialize
        if(!isFileManagerInit){
            // Setting default folder
            final String rootPath = String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));
            final File dir = new File(rootPath);
            // Creating file array
            files = dir.listFiles();
            // Displaying current path
            final TextView pathOutput = findViewById(R.id.pathOutput);
            // Setting pathOutput text to rootPath
            pathOutput.setText(rootPath.substring(rootPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1));
            // Number of files
            filesFoundCount = files.length;

            // Creating List elements and populating
            final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
            final TextAdapter textAdapter1 = new TextAdapter();
            listView.setAdapter(textAdapter1);

            filesList = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0; i < filesFoundCount; i++){
                filesList.add(String.valueOf(files[i].getAbsolutePath()));
            }

            textAdapter1.setData(filesList);

            // Allocating memory for array
            selection = new boolean[files.length];

            // To set item as selected
            listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // If unselected, select it
                    selection[position] = !selection[position];
                    // If selected, unselect it
                    textAdapter1.setSelection(selection);
                    boolean isAtLeastOneSelected = false;
                    // Checking if elements are selected
                    for(int i = 0; i < selection.length; i++){
                        if(selection[i]){
                            isAtLeastOneSelected = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    // If there are selections made, pull up the buttons on bottom
                    if(isAtLeastOneSelected){
                        findViewById(R.id.bottomBar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    // If there are no selections, then hide bottom bar
                    else{
                        findViewById(R.id.bottomBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            final Button b1 = findViewById(R.id.b1);
            final Button b2 = findViewById(R.id.b2);
            final Button b3 = findViewById(R.id.b3);
            final Button b4 = findViewById(R.id.b4);
            final Button b5 = findViewById(R.id.b5);

            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    deleteDialog.setTitle("Delete");
                    deleteDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this file/folder?");
                    deleteDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        // If user wants to delete
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
                                if(selection[i]){
                                    deleteFileOrFolder(files[i]);
                                    selection[i]=false;
                                }
                            }
                            files = dir.listFiles();
                            filesFoundCount = files.length;
                            filesList.clear();
                            for(int i = 0; i < filesFoundCount; i++){
                                filesList.add(String.valueOf(files[i].getAbsolutePath()));
                            }
                            textAdapter1.setData(filesList);
                        }
                    });
                    deleteDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    deleteDialog.show();
                }
            });

            // Setting isFileManagerInit to true
            isFileManagerInit = true;
        }


    }

    // Method that will delete file or folder
    private void deleteFileOrFolder(File fileOrFolder){
        // Check if file or directory
        // If folder
        if(fileOrFolder.isDirectory()){
            // If folder is empty
            if(fileOrFolder.list().length == 0){
                fileOrFolder.delete();
            }
            // Delete every file in the folder
            else{
                String files[] = fileOrFolder.list();
                for(String temp:files){
                    File fileToDelete = new File(fileOrFolder, temp);
                    deleteFileOrFolder(fileToDelete);
                }
                // Deleting folder itself
                if(fileOrFolder.list().length == 0){
                    fileOrFolder.delete();
                }
            }
        }
        // If just a file
        else{
            fileOrFolder.delete();
        }
    }

    // Checking if the user granted permissions
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, final String[] permissions,
                                           final int[] grantResults){
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        // If requestCode equal to request permissions and are not null
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS && grantResults.length>0){
            // If permissions denied, clear app data to continue asking user for permissions
            if(arePermissionsDenied() == true){
                // Requires 19 or higher, but will not be called anyway if that is the case, ignore warnings
                ((ActivityManager) Objects.requireNonNull(this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE))).clearApplicationUserData();
                recreate();
            }
            else{
                onResume();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This array declaration is invalid:

```
String files[] = fileOrFolder.list();
```

Don't over complicate the `deleteFileOrFolder()` method. Try it like this:

```java
    private boolean deleteFileOrFolder(File fileOrFolder){
        File[] files = fileOrFolder.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                deleteFileOrFolder(file);
            }
        }
        return fileOrFolder.delete();
    }
```